# Designing customised toggle switch in ionic

Tags: html, css, togglebutton

I want to design a toggle switch as shown below:

[image: ToggleSwitchModel]

I have developed a toggle switch. The details of the html and css code is given below. I want to know how to replce the circle with the bell icons.

```css
/* ============================================================
  RESET
============================================================ */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

del {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

a img {
  border: none;
}

/* ============================================================
  GLOBALS
============================================================ */
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #dc8c96;
  color: #505050;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.8;
}

/* Headings */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dc8c96;
}

a:hover {
  color: #ca5160;
}

/* clear floated divs */
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* ============================================================
  TEMPLATE
============================================================ */
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#main {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

/* ============================================================
  INFO BAR
============================================================ */
.info-bar {
  background-color: #ca5160;
  text-align: center;
}
.info-bar a.icon {
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.info-bar a.icon[data-title]:hover:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 20px;
  content: attr(data-title);
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #ca5160;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* ============================================================
  HEADER
============================================================ */
header .branding {
  padding: 30px 0;
  background-color: #dc8c96;
}
header .branding .container {
  padding: 0 30px 0 90px;
}
header .social {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 60px;
}
header .social a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 15px 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background-image: url("../img/core/social-light.png");
  background-image: url("../img/core/social-light.svg"), none;
  background-size: 180px 30px;
}
header .social a.fb {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
header .social a.twitter {
  background-position: -30px 0;
}
header .social a.googleplus {
  background-position: -60px 0;
}
header .social a.rss {
  background-position: -90px 0;
}
header .social a.email {
  background-position: -120px 0;
}
header .social a.search {
  background-position: -150px 0;
}
header .social a:hover {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
header .logo {
  float: left;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: -60px;
}
header .site-title {
  background-color: #ca5160;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
header .site-title h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
}

/* ============================================================
  FOOTER
============================================================ */
footer {
  padding: 30px 0;
}
footer .container {
  padding: 0 30px;
}
footer aside {
  width: 33.3333%;
  float: left;
}
footer aside.logo {
  text-align: right;
}
footer ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
footer ul a {
  color: #fff;
}
footer ul a:hover {
  color: #f4dadd;
}
footer .copyright {
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
footer .copyright span {
  color: #fff;
}
footer .copyright a {
  color: #f4dadd;
}

/* ============================================================
  FUSION ADS
============================================================ */
#fusionads {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 20;
  padding: 20px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: -2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#fusionads .fusion-wrap {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  width: 130px;
}
#fusionads a.fusion-text {
  display: block;
  color: #646464;
}
#fusionads a.fusion-img {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
#fusionads a.fusion-img img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
#fusionads a.fusion-poweredby {
  color: #ff3c50;
}

#close-fusionad {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 30;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #505050;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

/* ============================================================
  MEDIA QUERIES
============================================================ */
@media all and (max-width: 960px) {
  /* footer */
  footer aside {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  footer aside:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  footer aside.logo {
    text-align: center;
  }
  footer ul {
    text-align: center;
  }
  footer ul li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  footer ul li:after {
    content: "\2022";
  }
  footer ul li:last-child:after {
    content: none;
  }
  footer ul li a {
    margin: 0 10px;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 400px) {
  header .branding {
    padding: 15px 0;
  }
  header .branding .container {
    padding: 0 30px;
  }
  header .social {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    height: 30px;
  }
  header .social a {
    margin: 0 5px;
  }
  header .logo {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
}



/* ============================================================
  COMMON
============================================================ */
#wrapper {
  min-width: 600px;
}

.settings {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.settings .row {
  display: table-row;
}
.settings .question,
.settings .switch {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
}
.settings .question {
  width: 600px;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* ============================================================
  COMMON
============================================================ */
.cmn-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.cmn-toggle + label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* ============================================================
  SWITCH 1 - ROUND
============================================================ */
input.cmn-toggle-round + label {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 112px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  -ms-border-radius: 60px;
  -o-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round + label:before, input.cmn-toggle-round + label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  content: "";
}
input.cmn-toggle-round + label:before {
  right: 1px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;  
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  -ms-border-radius: 60px;
  -o-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.4s;
  -o-transition: background 0.4s;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round + label:before {
  background-color: red;
 /* background-image: url("../img/notOff.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
}

input.cmn-toggle-round + label:after {
  width: 50px;
   background-color: #fff;
 /*background-image: url("../img/notOn.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -ms-border-radius: 100%;
  -o-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: margin 0.4s;
  -o-transition: margin 0.4s;
  transition: margin 0.4s;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round + label:after {
 background-image: url("../img/notOff.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round + label:before {
 background-image: url("../img/notOn.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round:checked + label:before {
  background-color: #8ce196;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round:checked + label:after {
  margin-left: 60px;
}

/* ============================================================
  SWITCH 2 - ROUND FLAT
============================================================ */
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat + label {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  -ms-border-radius: 60px;
  -o-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.4s;
  -o-transition: background 0.4s;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat + label:before, input.cmn-toggle-round-flat + label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
}
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat + label:before {
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  -ms-border-radius: 60px;
  -o-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.4s;
  -o-transition: background 0.4s;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat + label:after {
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  width: 52px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 52px;
  -moz-border-radius: 52px;
  -ms-border-radius: 52px;
  -o-border-radius: 52px;
  border-radius: 52px;
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.4s, background 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: margin 0.4s, background 0.4s;
  -o-transition: margin 0.4s, background 0.4s;
  transition: margin 0.4s, background 0.4s;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat:checked + label {
  background-color: #8ce196;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat:checked + label:after {
  margin-left: 60px;
  background-color: #8ce196;
}

/* ============================================================
  SWITCH 3 - YES NO
============================================================ */
input.cmn-toggle-yes-no + label {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
}
input.cmn-toggle-yes-no + label:before, input.cmn-toggle-yes-no + label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
}
input.cmn-toggle-yes-no + label:before {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  content: attr(data-off);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
input.cmn-toggle-yes-no + label:after {
  background-color: #8ce196;
  content: attr(data-on);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
input.cmn-toggle-yes-no:checked + label:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
input.cmn-toggle-yes-no:checked + label:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(0);
  -o-transform: rotateY(0);
  transform: rotateY(0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
 <head>
   <!-- title and meta -->
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

   <title>CSS Toggle Switch</title>

   <!-- css -->
   <link href="css/base.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="js/toggle.js"></script>
   <!-- js -->
   <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="wrapper">
   <div id="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="settings">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="question">
    Do you like bananas?
     </div>
     <div class="switch">
    <input id="cmn-toggle-1" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" type="checkbox">
    <label for="cmn-toggle-1"></label>
     </div>
   </div><!-- /row -->
    </div>
  </div>
   </div><!-- #main -->  
 </div><!-- /#wrapper -->
 </body>
</html>
```

I want to replace the circle with the sample bell image given below:

[image: NotificationOffImg]

[image: NotificationOnImg]

Not sure how to do that. Please help.

Comment: http://idownvotedyoubecause.com/so/TooMuchCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go !! you only need to place your image as background.

```
input.cmn-toggle-round:checked + label:after {
  margin-left: 60px;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlAG5.png"); // your image
}
```

```css
/* ============================================================
  RESET
============================================================ */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

del {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

a img {
  border: none;
}

/* ============================================================
  GLOBALS
============================================================ */
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #dc8c96;
  color: #505050;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.8;
}

/* Headings */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dc8c96;
}

a:hover {
  color: #ca5160;
}

/* clear floated divs */
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* ============================================================
  TEMPLATE
============================================================ */
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#main {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

/* ============================================================
  INFO BAR
============================================================ */
.info-bar {
  background-color: #ca5160;
  text-align: center;
}
.info-bar a.icon {
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.info-bar a.icon[data-title]:hover:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 20px;
  content: attr(data-title);
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #ca5160;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* ============================================================
  HEADER
============================================================ */
header .branding {
  padding: 30px 0;
  background-color: #dc8c96;
}
header .branding .container {
  padding: 0 30px 0 90px;
}
header .social {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 60px;
}
header .social a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 15px 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background-image: url("../img/core/social-light.png");
  background-image: url("../img/core/social-light.svg"), none;
  background-size: 180px 30px;
}
header .social a.fb {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
header .social a.twitter {
  background-position: -30px 0;
}
header .social a.googleplus {
  background-position: -60px 0;
}
header .social a.rss {
  background-position: -90px 0;
}
header .social a.email {
  background-position: -120px 0;
}
header .social a.search {
  background-position: -150px 0;
}
header .social a:hover {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
header .logo {
  float: left;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: -60px;
}
header .site-title {
  background-color: #ca5160;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
header .site-title h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
}

/* ============================================================
  FOOTER
============================================================ */
footer {
  padding: 30px 0;
}
footer .container {
  padding: 0 30px;
}
footer aside {
  width: 33.3333%;
  float: left;
}
footer aside.logo {
  text-align: right;
}
footer ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
footer ul a {
  color: #fff;
}
footer ul a:hover {
  color: #f4dadd;
}
footer .copyright {
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
footer .copyright span {
  color: #fff;
}
footer .copyright a {
  color: #f4dadd;
}

/* ============================================================
  FUSION ADS
============================================================ */
#fusionads {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 20;
  padding: 20px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: -2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#fusionads .fusion-wrap {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  width: 130px;
}
#fusionads a.fusion-text {
  display: block;
  color: #646464;
}
#fusionads a.fusion-img {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
#fusionads a.fusion-img img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
#fusionads a.fusion-poweredby {
  color: #ff3c50;
}

#close-fusionad {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 30;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #505050;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

/* ============================================================
  MEDIA QUERIES
============================================================ */
@media all and (max-width: 960px) {
  /* footer */
  footer aside {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  footer aside:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  footer aside.logo {
    text-align: center;
  }
  footer ul {
    text-align: center;
  }
  footer ul li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  footer ul li:after {
    content: "\2022";
  }
  footer ul li:last-child:after {
    content: none;
  }
  footer ul li a {
    margin: 0 10px;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 400px) {
  header .branding {
    padding: 15px 0;
  }
  header .branding .container {
    padding: 0 30px;
  }
  header .social {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    height: 30px;
  }
  header .social a {
    margin: 0 5px;
  }
  header .logo {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
}



/* ============================================================
  COMMON
============================================================ */
#wrapper {
  min-width: 600px;
}

.settings {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.settings .row {
  display: table-row;
}
.settings .question,
.settings .switch {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
}
.settings .question {
  width: 600px;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* ============================================================
  COMMON
============================================================ */
.cmn-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.cmn-toggle + label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* ============================================================
  SWITCH 1 - ROUND
============================================================ */
input.cmn-toggle-round + label {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 112px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  -ms-border-radius: 60px;
  -o-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round + label:before, input.cmn-toggle-round + label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  content: "";
}
input.cmn-toggle-round + label:before {
  right: 1px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;  
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  -ms-border-radius: 60px;
  -o-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.4s;
  -o-transition: background 0.4s;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round + label:before {
  background-color: red;
 /* background-image: url("../img/notOff.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
}

input.cmn-toggle-round + label:after {
  width: 50px;
   background-color: #fff;
 background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlAG5.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -ms-border-radius: 100%;
  -o-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: margin 0.4s;
  -o-transition: margin 0.4s;
  transition: margin 0.4s;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round + label:after {
 background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/MF9Yy.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round + label:before {
 background-image: url("../img/notOn.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round:checked + label:before {
  background-color: #8ce196;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round:checked + label:after {
  margin-left: 60px;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlAG5.png");
}

/* ============================================================
  SWITCH 2 - ROUND FLAT
============================================================ */
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat + label {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  -ms-border-radius: 60px;
  -o-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.4s;
  -o-transition: background 0.4s;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat + label:before, input.cmn-toggle-round-flat + label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
}
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat + label:before {
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  -ms-border-radius: 60px;
  -o-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.4s;
  -o-transition: background 0.4s;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat + label:after {
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  width: 52px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 52px;
  -moz-border-radius: 52px;
  -ms-border-radius: 52px;
  -o-border-radius: 52px;
  border-radius: 52px;
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.4s, background 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: margin 0.4s, background 0.4s;
  -o-transition: margin 0.4s, background 0.4s;
  transition: margin 0.4s, background 0.4s;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat:checked + label {
  background-color: #8ce196;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat:checked + label:after {
  margin-left: 60px;
  background-color: #8ce196;
}

/* ============================================================
  SWITCH 3 - YES NO
============================================================ */
input.cmn-toggle-yes-no + label {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
}
input.cmn-toggle-yes-no + label:before, input.cmn-toggle-yes-no + label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
}
input.cmn-toggle-yes-no + label:before {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  content: attr(data-off);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
input.cmn-toggle-yes-no + label:after {
  background-color: #8ce196;
  content: attr(data-on);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
input.cmn-toggle-yes-no:checked + label:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
input.cmn-toggle-yes-no:checked + label:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(0);
  -o-transform: rotateY(0);
  transform: rotateY(0);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="settings">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="question">
    Do you like bananas?
     </div>
     <div class="switch">
    <input id="cmn-toggle-1" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" type="checkbox">
    <label for="cmn-toggle-1"></label>
     </div>
   </div><!-- /row -->
    </div>
  </div>
   </div><!-- #main -->  
 </div><!-- /#wrapper -->
```